# Multiple select tag under one id

Tags: jquery, html, select

I am appending multiple select element inside an id called `append` like the following.

```
<div id="append">
    <select name="color[]" id="colorsData1" class="form-control">
        <option>--Select any One--</option>
        <option>Red</option>
        <option>Yellow</option>
        <option>Blue</option>
        <option>Black</option>
    </select>

    <select name="color[]" id="colorsData2" class="form-control">
        <option>--Select any One--</option>
        <option>Red</option>
        <option>Yellow</option>
        <option>Blue</option>
        <option>Black</option>
    </select>
    <select name="color[]" id="colorsData3" class="form-control">
        <option>--Select any One--</option>
        <option>Red</option>
        <option>Yellow</option>
        <option>Blue</option>
        <option>Black</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

Now, to prevent the data duplication, I want to use condition if the user selects color red and as the color red has already been selected before either in colorsData1 or colorsData2, I want to alert user. How do I check if the any of the selected options before matches the current selected option?

The reason for using multiple select rather than checkboxes is because I am making an e-commerce website, actually. And for the stock management I am cloning div [image: please see this image] where vendor can upload images according to the colors they select. I am also appending upload field if there is no color duplication. If the selected option is not duplicate my whole div would look like this. [image: Please see another image.]

And, the reason for me to check the colour duplication is not to alert the vendor but for myself. Right after the vendor makes a color selection, if the colour has already been selected before I want to divert my code to else condition where there is not code to append the fileupload field. See, vendor can have shoes of Nike of different sizes with same colors. Sizes does not matter on online shopping as they cannot tell them if it fits to them by looking at the image. So, I am allowing vendor to upload products with same color but different sizes for stock management.
There is a button with id addnew and following is my jquery code after clicking on that button:

```
$('#addnew').on('click', function(){ 
        num = num+1;
        let html = '';
        html = '<div class="form-group row div"><div class="col-md-2 col-lg-2"><select name="color[]" id="colorsData'+num+'" class="form-control selectebox"><option>--Select any One--</option></select></div><div class="col-md-3 col-lg-3"><select class="select2 form-control" name="size[]" multiple="multiple" id="sizesData'+num+'"></select></div><div class="col-md-2 col-lg-2"><input type="number" placeholder="availability" name="stock" class="form-control h-100"></div><div class="col-md-2 col-lg-2"><input class="form-control h-100" value="" type="text" name="price[]" placeholder="price"></div><div class="col-md-3 col-lg-3"><input class="form-control h-100" value="" type="text" name="discount[]" placeholder="discount"></div></div>';
        $('#append').append(html);
        if(num == 1){
            html = '<div class="form-group row image"><div class="col-md-12 col-lg-12" style="display:inherit"><a href="/vendor/filemanager/dialog.php?type=4&amp;field_id=thumbnail'+num+'&amp;descending=1&amp;sort_by=date&amp;lang=undefined&amp;akey=061e0de5b8d667cbb7548b551420eb821075e7a6" class="btn iframe-btn btn-primary" type="button"><i class="fa fa-picture-o"></i> Choose</a><input id="thumbnail'+num+'" class="form-control h-100" value="" type="text" name="image[]"></div></div>';
            $('#append').append(html);
            responsive_filemanager_callback('thumbnail'+num);
        } else {
            var selected_color = []; 
                $(".selectebox").on('change',function(){  console.log(selected_color)
                if(jQuery.inArray( this.value, selected_color)){
                    alert('duplicate color')
                } else {
                    html = '<div class="form-group row image"><div class="col-md-12 col-lg-12" style="display:inherit"><a href="/vendor/filemanager/dialog.php?type=4&amp;field_id=thumbnail'+num+'&amp;descending=1&amp;sort_by=date&amp;lang=undefined&amp;akey=061e0de5b8d667cbb7548b551420eb821075e7a6" class="btn iframe-btn btn-primary" type="button"><i class="fa fa-picture-o"></i> Choose</a><input id="thumbnail'+num+'" class="form-control h-100" value="" type="text" name="image[]"></div></div>';
                    $('#append').append(html);
                    responsive_filemanager_callback('thumbnail'+num);
                }
                selected_color.push($(this).val());
            });
        }

    })
```

and following is my code on HTML

```
<div class="page-body">
<form action="{{ route('products.store') }}" method="POST">
    @csrf
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-12">
            <div class="card">
                <div class="card-header">
                    <h5>What you're selling</h5>
                </div>
                <div class="card-block">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-12">
                            <div class="form-group row">
                                <div class="col-md-4 col-lg-2">
                                    <label for="name" class="block">Product Name *</label>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-md-8 col-lg-10">
                                    <input name="name" type="text" class="required form-control" id="name">
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group row">
                                <div class="col-md-4 col-lg-2">
                                    <label for="slug" class="block">Product Slug *</label>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-md-8 col-lg-10">
                                    <input name="slug" type="text" class="required form-control" id="slug">
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group row">
                                <div class="col-md-4 col-lg-2">
                                    <label for="category-2" class="block">Category *</label>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-md-8 col-lg-10">
                                    <select name="category_id" id="category_id" class="requires form-control">
                                        <option selected disabled>--Product Category--</option>
                                        <option value="">Hair</option>
                                        <option value="">Perfumes</option>
                                        <option value="">Shoes</option>
                                    </select>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group row">
                                <div class="col-md-4 col-lg-2">
                                    <label for="brand-2" class="block">Brand *</label>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-md-8 col-lg-10">
                                    <select name="brand_id" id="brand_id" class="requires form-control">
                                        <option selected disabled>--Product Brand--</option>
                                        <option value="">Nike</option>
                                        <option value="">Zivah</option>
                                        <option value="">Caliber</option>
                                    </select>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-12">
            <div class="card">
                <div class="card-header">
                    <h5>General Information</h5>
                </div>
                <div class="card-block">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-12">
                            <div class="form-group row">
                                <div class="col-md-4 col-lg-2">
                                    <label for="description-2" class="block">Product description *</label>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-md-8 col-lg-10">
                                    <textarea name="description" id="description" rows="10" class="form-control editor"></textarea>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group row">
                                <div class="col-md-4 col-lg-2">
                                    <label for="description-2" class="block">Video URL </label>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-md-8 col-lg-10">
                                    <input type="url" name="video" placeholder="video url" class="form-control">
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-12">
            <div class="card">
                <div class="card-header">
                    <h5>SKU Information</h5>
                    <br>
                    <span class="hint">Click on the plus button to add the SKU of the product.</span>
                </div>
                <div class="card-block">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-12">
                            <div id="append"></div>
                            <div class="form-group text-center">
                                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="addnew"><span class="icofont icofont-ui-add"></span></button>
                                <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" id="delete"><span class="icofont icofont-ui-delete"></span></button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-12">
            <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Save Changes" class="btn btn-success pull-right" id="submit">
        </div>
    </div>

</form>
```

Comment: Why don't you use another control for that, like a series of checkboxes, one per color, or a multiselect list?

Comment: @trincot. I have edited my question please review it.

Comment: I don't see any reason why not to use checkboxes.

Comment: Your question should have all the HTML necessary to answer the question. There currently is no size in there, no upload field. If you want more complex logic, then your question should mention that, with example input and expected output /behaviour. I will delete my answer, as I wasted time on a question that was not complete/clear.

Comment: @trincot I have uploaded the images in the question where one has upload field and I have also mention that I will be appending file upload field if there is no color duplication.

Comment: Images are not code.

Comment: @trincot You can see the full code.

Comment: What about HTML?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/207830/discussion-between-eliesha-and-trincot).

Answer (score 0):

1. Add CSS class colour to every dropdown `class="form-control color"`
2. Add unique value for each option in the dropdown `<option value="1" >Red</option>`
3. Add on change event listener all the dropdown - `selectcolor(this)`.
4. "`selectcolor`" function will check the duplication.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script>
  function selectcolor(a) {
   console.log(a);
   var data_list = new Set();
   $(".color").each(function(i,e){
    let val = $(e).val();
    if(val != ""){
     if(data_list.has(val)){ // checking is already selected
      alert("Already exist");
      $(e).val(""); // resetting the drop down
     }else{
      data_list.add(val)
     }
    } 
    
   });
  }
   onchange="selectcolor(this);" 
 </script>
 <div id="append">
  <select name="color[]" onchange="selectcolor(this);" id="colorsData1" class="form-control color">
   <option value="" >--Select any One--</option>
   <option value="1" >Red</option>
   <option value="2" >Yellow</option>
   <option value="3">Blue</option>
   <option value="4">Black</option>
  </select>

  <select name="color[]" id="colorsData2" class="form-control color"  onchange="selectcolor(this);" >

    <option  value="" >--Select any One--</option>
   <option value="1" >Red</option>
   <option value="2" >Yellow</option>
   <option value="3">Blue</option>
   <option value="4">Black</option>
  </select>
  <select name="color[]" id="colorsData3" class="form-control color"  onchange="selectcolor(this);" >
    
   <option  value=""  >--Select any One--</option>
   <option value="1" >Red</option>
   <option value="2" >Yellow</option>
   <option value="3">Blue</option>
   <option value="4">Black</option>
  </select>
 </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score -1):

this will help you

```js
var selected_color = [];
$(".selectebox").on('change',function(){
  if(selected_color.includes($(this).val())){
   alert("This color already selected");
   $(this).val("");
  }
selected_color.push($(this).val());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="append">
<select name="color[]" id="colorsData1"  class="form-control selectebox">
   <option value = "">--Select any One--</option>
   <option value = "Red">Red</option>
   <option value = "Yellow">Yellow</option>
   <option value = "Blue">Blue</option>
   <option value = "Black"> Black</option>
</select>

<select name="color[]" id="colorsData2" class="form-control selectebox">
   <option value = "" >--Select any One--</option>
   <option value = "Red">Red</option>
   <option value = "Yellow">Yellow</option>
   <option value = "Blue">Blue</option>
   <option value = "Black"> Black</option>
</select>
<select name="color[]" id="colorsData3" class="form-control selectebox">
   <option value = "">--Select any One--</option>
   <option value = "Red">Red</option>
   <option value = "Yellow">Yellow</option>
   <option value = "Blue">Blue</option>
   <option value = "Black"> Black</option>
</select>
</div>
```

Comment: I did a console.log(selected_color). It consoles the colors that were selected. There is no error. This condition `if(selected_color.includes($(this).val()))` is not working.

Comment: Code has a bugg. If you'll remove selected option you won't able to use this option anymore, cause it's exists in array.

Comment: @trincot. Yep, thank you so much for being consistent with my post. I want to go with select rather than checkboxes. I saw your answer but what if the vendor ignores the message and submit data with duplicate entries?